# Making checked out documents visible to all users

Tags: document-library, permissions, view, check-out

So on our Office365 I've noticed that users cannot view files that have been checked out by other users. Is there a permission or library setting that does allow users to see files that have been checked out by other users?

It is possible to do this by setting "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" to No, but I'd rather leave that setting on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that users cannot see files that are checked out, it's that users cannot see files that have never been checked in. Once the initial checkin has happened it is visible to all users, even if it's subsequently checked out.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks. Is it not possible then to make documents that have never been checked in to be visible to users in their draft state?

Comment: no, because the checking in is what makes it visible.  Well, you could make everyone site collection admins...that would solve that problem but create a bunch more :)